# My flags are being declined

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, flag-ban

So my flags on bad posts aren't good enough, according to some, but all my flagged posts have minus something votes and all of them are closed...

Like this one, for example

[image]

What's the problem ?

Comment: As an example: what a [VLQ post](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26814397/5) would look like, and what an [unclear what you're asking post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26975025/bootstrap-grid-unable-to-get-hidden-value-to-next-tab-while-debugging-in-brow) would look like. It takes a lot to actually get the post into territory where none of the other flags work, such as OT, Unclear, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *"minus something"* (-6 in the above screen shot) is the current score of the question you have flagged. It should not have anything to do with the flag type you have raised nor motivate your to flag a question. You will soon find that even questions with a positive score sometimes need a flag/closure.

Don't let the score fool you that a question needs a flag - judge the content of the answer and not its current score.

The text in red is the reason your flag has been declined.

I believe we are talking about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26889080/2140173). The correct flag should be that the question is `too - broad`. It needed closing as being too broad rather than deleting due to being badly formatted and not understandable.

Answer (score 6):

Don't use the Very Low Quality flag unless a post is pretty nigh unintelligible.  The description for that flag is:

> This question has severe formatting or content problems. This question is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

If a post could easily be fixed with an edit by the OP, then we don't need to see a VLQ flag on it. Just leave a comment asking the OP for clarification, edit it yourself if you can, downvote it if you want... there are a lot of tools at your disposal. The VLQ flag should be one of the last ones you choose.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that all of the posts you're flagging are downvoted and often closed means that you're flagging the *right posts*, but the fact that your flags are being declined means you're like flagging them for the ***wrong reasons***. If you look at the responses to your flags, there will be some explanation of why the flag was inappropriate for the question - in the example screenshot, it's that while there may have been something wrong with the question, that problem wasn't that it was so low quality that no possible edits could have turned it into a good question. You ought to spend more time determining what the correct flag reason is before flagging, once your ban expires.